# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object error in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to do something, and for some reason I get an error:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Player:

```
    public GoTo sentFrom;
    private void Update()
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        if (transform.position.y < -5)
        {
            sentFrom.GoToAuto("YouDied", "tuturial1");
        }
    }
```

GoTo:

```
    static public string WentFrom;
    public void GoToAuto(string to, string from)
    {
        WentFrom = from;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(to);
    }
```

Thank You :D

Comment: You didn't provide relevant definitions for classes such as `GoTo`, but if I had to guess, you never created an instance of `GoTo` when declaring `sentFrom`. So `sentFrom.GoToAuto(...)` is not set to an instance of `GoTo`, hence the object reference error. This error always has to do with referencing an object that has not been instantiated. Try `public GoTo sentFrom = new GoTo();`

Comment: Please refrain from applying tags to your questions that don't apply.  This isn't C, and read the Visual Studio tags:  " DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."